# How can I import an external file with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a node app that has a string of `require`s, like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = require('./router'),
    data = require('./data');
```

This code works without changes, but how can I take full advantage of TypeScript modules? Just using

```
import data = module("./data")
```

will tell me

> The name ''./data'' does not exist in the current scope

How can I import an external file with TypeScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example,

> http://www.typescriptlang.org/Samples/#ImageBoard

contains a file called `node.d.ts` which shows how to declare the types for an existing node.js module.

TypeScript requires the module be declared for you use to `import` syntax. This is typically provided in a `.d.ts` file but can be included in the same file. An example this might look like,

```
declare module "./data" {
    function getData(): number;
}

import data = module("./data");

var myData = data.getData();
```

In a `.d.ts` file the `declare` keywords is implied and can be omitted.

Comment: It does not seem to work in the current (1.0) version of typescript compiler.