# How to reference a class in another TypeScript file?

Tags: typescript

How do i get access to classes in another `.ts` file in TypeScript?

e.g.

**app.ts**

```
window.onload = () => {
   /// <reference path="TilingEngine/SofRenderer.ts" >
   var drawingTool = new SofRenderer();
};
```

**TilingEngine/SofRenderer.ts**

```
class SofRenderer {
}
```

Fails to compile, with the error:

> Could not find symbol 'SofRenderer'.

### See also

- [How can I import an external file with TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699940/how-can-i-import-an-external-file-with-typescript) (i'm not using node)
- [How do I import other TypeScript files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930049/how-do-i-import-other-typescript-files) (i'm not using modules)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your reference comment should be at the top of your file and be self-closing. Like this:

```
///<reference path="TilingEngine/SofRenderer.ts" />
window.onload = () => {
   var drawingTool = new SofRenderer();
};
```

Comment: When i first read the answer, i read it as *"Your reference comment at the top should be **self-closing**".* Wasn't until another reading that i noticed the **should be at the top**.

Comment: It is quite strict about this for some reason :)

Comment: you also need to decorate the classes/interfaces/etc with the keyword 'export' in your source .ts file.