# TypeScript Reference Class File Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I am trying to include one TypeScript class file, `Mandelbrot.ts`, inside of another file `app.ts`. After having tried [the solution in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17243733/663604), I cannot get it to work.

#### app.ts

```
/// <reference path="Mandelbrot.ts" />

window.onload = function() {
    var mandelbrot = new Mandelbrot("canvas");
};
```

#### Mandelbrot.ts (same folder as app.ts)

```
class Mandelbrot {
    ...
}
```

#### app.js (Compiled output)

```
/// <reference path="Mandelbrot.ts" />
window.onload = function () {
    var mandelbrot = new Mandelbrot("canvas");
};
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

It appears as though the compiler ignored my reference request, as nothing works in the browser. There aren't any compiler errors or warnings. I am using the compiler which is part of Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want files to get imported based on reference comments you need to compile with "--out"

Having said that I feel out is a bad idea : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md you should look at requirejs or systemjs